# Vigenere Square Decryption in C

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, vigenere

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a message using a passphrase and a vigenere square stored in an array. I am able to encrypt the message successfully however I can't work out how to decrypt it again afterwards. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encrypt(char *text, char *pass, int n, int m, char *vs);
void decrypt(char *text, char *pass, int n, int m, char *vs);
void vigsq(char *vs);

main()
{
     char text[] = "HELLOWORLD";
     char pass[] = "MAGIC";
     int n, m;
     char vs[26*26];
     char *vsPointer, *textPointer, *passPointer;
     char command;
     char inputfile[10];
     char outputfile[10];
     //printf("Please enter e/d, pass phrase, input file, output file:");
     //scanf("%c, %s, %s, %s", &command, &pass, &inputfile, &outputfile);
     vsPointer = vs;
     textPointer = text;
     passPointer = pass;
     vigsq(vsPointer);
     //printf("%c, %s, %s, %s\n", command, pass, inputfile, outputfile);

    n = strlen(text);
    m = strlen(pass);
    //printf("%d, %d", n, m);
    encrypt(textPointer, passPointer, n, m, vsPointer);
    printf("%s\n", text);
    decrypt(textPointer, passPointer, n, m, vsPointer);
    printf("%s\n", text);   
}

void encrypt(char *text, char *pass, int n, int m, char *vs)
{
    int i;
    int ascii1;
    int ascii2;
    int passcount = 0;
    char encrypt;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ascii1 = (int)text[i];
        ascii2 = (int)pass[passcount];
        ascii1 = ascii1 - 64;
        ascii2 = ascii2 - 64;
        encrypt = vs[((ascii1 -1)*26) + (ascii2)];
        // printf("%d, %d, %c\n", ascii1, ascii2, encrypt);
        text[i] = encrypt;
        passcount++;
        if (passcount == m)
        {
            passcount = 0;
        }
    }   
}

void decrypt(char *text, char *pass, int n, int m, char *vs)
{
    int i;
    int ascii1;
    int ascii2;
    int passcount = 0;
    char decrypt;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ascii1 = (int)text[i];
        ascii2 = (int)pass[passcount];
        ascii1 = ascii1 - 64;
        ascii2 = ascii2 - 64;
        decrypt = vs[//Don't know what to put here];
        //printf("%d, %d, %c\n", ascii1, ascii2, decrypt);
        text[i] = decrypt;
        passcount++;
        if (passcount == m)
        {
            passcount = 0;
        }
    }       
}

void vigsq(char *vs)
{
    char alphabet[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
        'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    int a = 0, i, j, count = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= 26*26; i++)
    {                           
        vs[i] = alphabet[a];
        a++;
        if (i % 26 == 0)
        {
            count++;
            a = count;
        }   
        if (a == 26)        
        {
            a = 0;
        }               
    }
}
```

(Please ignore the I/O stuff I'll be implementing that later.)
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Voting to close *(Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encode a letter, you look up letter at the the row of the password letter `m[j]` and the columns of the plaintext letter `p[i]` in the Vigenère table. When you decode, you must find the column where encrypted letter `c[i]` is in the row of the password letter. In code, encrypting is a simple table lookup, but decrypting is not.

You don't really need the table, though. You can describe the Vigenère cipher algorithmically. The cipher really is just a Ceasar cipher – a simple letter shift &ndash, where the shift amount is determined by the current letter in the password. Encrypting means shifting forwards, decrypting means shifting backwards:

```
c[i] = (p[i] + m[j]) % 26
p[i] = (c[i] - m[j]) & 26
```

In this formula, the letters are represented by the numbers 0 (A) to 25 (Z). Remember that indices start at zero in C. That also means that you have to subtract `'A'` (65) from your letters, not 64.

Because decryption and encryption are so similar, you can implement them in a single function with a flag for the mode of operation:

```
enum {
    Encrypt, 
    Decrypt
};                    

void vigenere(char *text, const char *pass, int mode)
{
    int i;
    int passcount = 0;

    for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int ascii1 = text[i] - 'A';
        int ascii2 = pass[passcount] - 'A';

        // Negate shift for decryption
        if (mode == Decrypt) ascii2 = -ascii2;

        text[i] = 'A' + (26 + ascii1 + ascii2) % 26;

        passcount++;
        if (pass[passcount] == '\0') passcount = 0;
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- The addition of 26 in the formula is to prevent taking the remainder of a negative number, which will yield a negative number in C.
- The code works only if all characters are upper-case letters.
- The explicit string lengths have been omitted; you can test whether you have reached the end of a C string by checking whather the current character is the terminating null, `'\0'`.

Call this code like so:

```
int main()
{
    char text[] = "HELLOWORLD";
    const char *pass = "MAGIC";

    printf("plain %s\n", text);    

    vigenere(text, pass, Encrypt);
    printf("crypt %s\n", text);

    vigenere(text, pass, Decrypt);
    printf("decpt %s\n", text); 

    return 0;  
}
```